# Convert multidimensional array to string and push to new array

Tags: php

I have an array something like this:

```
array:6 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "2"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    0 => "2"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "3"
  ]
```

From this array, I have to form a number 123, 132, .... and push it to the new array.

I have tried following code which in return gives null value.

```
$finalArr = array();
array_map(function($item) use ($finalArr) {
    $list = implode($item);
    if (!in_array($list, $finalArr)) {
        array_push($finalArr, $list);
    }
}, $results);

dd($finalArr)
```

Comment: isn't it just simply `echo implode(', ', array_map('implode', $results));`? apply `implode` to each sub batch, then `implode` again on the main batch

Comment: and your `use` import won't work if you don't apply any reference `&$finalArr`

Comment: Every answer there are actually working for you. However, I noticed you want to remove duplicated values. You can apply `array_unique()` to the result of each answer posted there

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below code

```
$data = array(
  '0' => array(
    '0' => "1",
    '1' => "2",
    '2' => "3",
  ),
  '1' => array(
    '0' => "1",
    '1' => "3",
    '2' => "2",
  ),
  '2' => array(
    '0' => "2",
    '1' => "1",
    '2' => "3",
  ),
);


$finalArray = array();

foreach( $data as $d ) {
    $finalArray[] = implode('', $d);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArray);
```

Please see online demo [here](https://3v4l.org/24jCF)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) to apply [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on each array.

```
print_r(array_map("implode",$arr));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/NG9Mf

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
foreach($multidimentsion_array as $array){
    $value = join("",$array);
    $result[$value] = $value;
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_map('implode', $yourArray);
```

This should be all that you need to get an array with joined strings. If you need to push them to another array afterwards, you can do just that:

```
array_push($otherArray, ...array_map('implode', $yourArray));
```